# fix debian libc-bin

Tags: debian, apt

Apparently I broke my Debian system again.

If I want to install anything using `apt` I get the following warning:

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.25) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Following this hint is no use, as it only results in

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bc cups-browsed cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers
  cups-ppdc cups-server-common dc foomatic-db-compressed-ppds foomatic-db-engine hp-ppd
  hplip-data libart-2.0-2 libavahi-glib1 libcupscgi1 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libfontembed1 libgutenprint2 libhpmud0 liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml-data
  liblouisutdml7 libqpdf17 libsane-hpaio libsnmp-base libsnmp30 mscompress
  openprinting-ppds printer-driver-all printer-driver-brlaser printer-driver-c2050
  printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-cjet printer-driver-dymo printer-driver-escpr
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-fujixerox
  printer-driver-hpijs printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-min12xxw
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr
  printer-driver-sag-gdi python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-ptyprocess
  python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel qpdf ssl-cert
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups hplip libc-bin locales printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix task-english task-print-server
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 22.0 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

A quick Google search informed me that removing `libc-bin` is a terrible idea, which and idiot like me should never do. The question is now, how can I fix my problem?

---

Further info:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180310-11:21]/ stretch main
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180310-11:21]/ stretch main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

---

Requested by comments:

`$ sudo apt install libc-bin/stable`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc-bin is already the newest version (2.24-11+deb9u3).
Selected version '2.24-11+deb9u3' (Debian:9.4/stable [amd64]) for 'libc-bin'
Selected version '2.24-11+deb9u3' (Debian:9.4/stable [amd64]) for 'libc6' because of 'libc-bin'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.25) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

```
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic main
```

`$ apt-cache policy`

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=9.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=9.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

`$dpkg --list libc6`

```
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
+++-================-=============-=============-=====================================
ii  libc6:amd64      2.27-3        amd64         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

`find /lib -name libc-\*`

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: I suspect you have an odd version of libc installed, what is the output of the following commands:  `dpkg --list libc6` and `find /lib -name libc-\*`.

Comment: @GAD3R I already tried `apt --reinstall install libc-bin`, but this prompts just the error of `unmet dependencies` that I pointed out already.

Comment: I had same problem. Fixed by downloading libc-bin deb file manually from Debian repo and installing it with dpkg -i, then running apt --fix-broken install

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you've somehow installed (or at least convinced dpkg that it's available) a newer version of the `locales` package. The one available in Stretch only depends on `libc-bin (>> 2.24)`, while your output shows that your `apt` sees a version depending on `libc-bin (> 2.27)` (you might say it's inconsistent that `dpkg` uses `>>` in dependencies and `apt` outputs `>` in cases like this, that's the way it is, they mean the same).

The `locales` package is not essential, so I would try to remove that and then install it again afterwards, if you have a lot of locales compiled that might take a while.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seams that removing `locales` doesn't change anything.  Removing it results in `libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.25) but 2.27-3 is to be installed`  
`task-english : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed
`

Comment: I won't rule out that your system can be saved, but it's not going to be easy and it needs more information and more interaction than really fits SE (maybe the chat works).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am willing to provide any information I can. I just have no knowledge of Linux and currently waiting in an airport with 1KiB/s connection.